# Cannot recurse over object[] because cannot convert object to object[]

Tags: .net, recursion, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create a deep reverse for an object[]. I use a type check to see if there is another object[] inside the first object, and if so, recurse into that array. When there are no more object[]s to step inside, we reverse the array. That seems like it would work to reverse the whole thing, but I'm getting an error when I pass the object[] into the method when its found.

Here's my code:

```
    private static void deepReverse(object[] argArr)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < argArr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (argArr[i].GetType() == typeof(object[]))
            {
                deepReverse(argArr[i]);
            }
        }
        Array.Reverse(argArr);
    }
```

At the deepReverse(argArr[i]) I get an error "Cannot convert from 'object' to 'object[].'

I don't understand this because that is what the typecheck does. The if statement is checking to make sure that index does in fact hold an 'object[].' If it finds that index to hold a 'object[]' how come I can't pass it as an object[]?

This is a small helper method to help with something else which is why I'm using object[] instead of something more specific. In this case I need to use that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for the compiler to know that argArr[i] is anything but an 'object'. You obviously know it because of the 'if' conditional branch. I think that you should simple cast the function parameter:

```
 deepReverse((object [])argArr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`argArr` is an array of objects, so each element of `argArr` will be an object.
since you want to pass element of `argArr` to `deepReverse` so IDE will alert error. You need to convert `argArr[i]` to an array of objects (object[]) before passing it to `deepReverse`